# Image Resizer .net Azure Private Blob Access

Tags: azure, blob, imageresizer

Been trying to figure this out, but I have a private blob that contains a demo image, and I'm trying to access it through the resizer application.  I am using the secondary connection string to the blob, and it just seems to keep throwing a 404 error

Here is the link to the gist

https://gist.github.com/dbassassin/d95d4d8f7f21c9d6ee32

Any help is appreciated, I keep thinking it's just a matter of authentication or that I'm missing something.

My Web.config holds:

```
  <resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="AzureReader2"
      prefix="~/"
      connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountnamehere;AccountKey=secretstuffhere==;"
      endpoint="https://cvcdbsaz01.blob.core.windows.net/"
      />
    </plugins>
    <diagnostics enableFor="allhosts" />
  </resizer>
```

Comment: What URL are you using to access the blob?

Comment: I've tried both:

http://resizertests20160304023621.azurewebsites.net/images/modular2.jpg

and 

https://cvcdbsaz01.blob.core.windows.net/images/modular2.jpg

The fist link seems to redirect to the second link

Answer (score 0):

Set redirectToBlobIfUnmodified="false" - AzureReader2 currently can only proxy private blobs; it can't redirect to them and generate a shared access signature.

Also, verify that you can access the blob within your container directly from C#. It's possible the credentials or container/path you're using is incorrect.

Comment: Still doesn't work, and I was able to use a console application to access the container and list the contents :/

Comment: Here is the error message if it helps

@nathaniel jones

[FileNotFoundException: Azure blob file not found]
   ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.<OpenAsync>d__14.MoveNext() +409

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and see what parameters are being passed to the Azure SDK? You might clone https://github.com/imazen/resizer and build the the two projects as part of your solution  to make debugging easier.